# Can't pull or push after git clone - local changes

Tags: git

I created a new directory c:\Src, where I've cloned a repository. After cloning I get the following

```
$ git branch  
* Search

$ git branch -a  
* Search  
remotes/origin/master  
remotes/origin/prototype
```

If i then try

```
$ git checkout -b master origin/master
```

it returns

```
error: You have local changes to '<some_file>'; cannot switch branches
```

pull gives the same error.

I have not made any changes, and I'm confused why it doesn't use the master branch as default?

Comment: What does "git config -l" show?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you might want to checkout a tracking branch for master. You can use `-t` or `-track` instead of the `-b` (or if you have a recent version of git you can just use `git checkout origin/master` and it will automatically create a tracking branch).

As for your specific error, you should run `git status` to see if you have any local changes. If you do, you can then run `git stash`, do your checkout/pull and then `git stash pop` afterwards.

Comment: nice answer, but i think `git stash apply` is safer for beginners, as they won't loose the stashed changes and don't have to mess with the reflog