# How to sync android repo after making changes?

Tags: android, git, repository, android-source, cyanogenmod

I have downloaded Android source code with repo, then I made some changes in frameworks/base/packages. Now when I trying to do repo sync, it gives me this error:

> Syncing work tree:  60% (151/251)  error: You have local changes to
>   'packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java';
>   cannot switch branches.

How to fix it and upgrade all the projects that have no changes?

Comment: You can do a "[git stash](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html)" and "git stash apply" in frameworks/base for instance.

Comment: Using the repo tools, I get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` because there isn't a .git directory.  Just a .repo directory.

Comment: Hi, Getting the same error. Any comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jens comments, [stashing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html) is a good option here (for *uncommitted* changed.
It allows to save your local modification, `git pull` and `git stash apply` said modifications back.
See for instance "[Can't pull or push after git clone - local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618080/cant-pull-or-push-after-git-clone-local-changes)".

If you had already committed changes, it would be best to:

- make a `tmp` branch at your current HEAD
- reset `HEAD` to `origin/master`
- re-try the `repo sync`.
- merge `tmp` to `master`

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to stash. It has .repo and not .git. Giving me error fatal: not a git repository

Comment: @Ghost If I read http://stackoverflow.com/a/11870480/6309 correctly, the git repo is in `.repo/repo` or in `.repo/projects/xxx`